Draw arrow ending on line of best fit with ggplot2 and grid
I am trying to annotate a ggplot2 line of best fit for a scatterplot with an arrow.
This replicates an example in Paul Murrell's book R Graphics (Third Edition), though that example modifies grobs on the grid display list whereas I would like to do it by manipulating the grobs produced by ggplot2. Code for the original example is here (Figure 7.16).
I want to write 'Line of best fit' in the plot region and draw an arrow from this, ending on the actual line of best fit.
It is perhaps useful to explain that my motivation is to learn more about how the grid package works, so I would like to find a solution using grid.
I have almost got this to work but cannot find the right way to place the end of the arrow as it points to the bottom of the confidence interval ribbon instead of the line itself.
Code so far:
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = TRUE)

gg <- ggplotGrob(p)

# Retrieve the panel grob
panel_grob <- gg[["grobs"]][gg$layout$name == "panel"][[1]]

child_nms <- names(panel_grob[["children"]])

# Which child of the "panel" grob contains "smooth" in its name?
smooth_idx <- which(grepl("smooth", child_nms))
smooth_grob <- panel_grob$children[smooth_idx][[1]]

# Which child of the "smooth" grob contains "line" in its name?
line_idx <- which(grepl("line", names(smooth_grob$children)))
polyline_grob <- smooth_grob$children[line_idx][[1]]

# Create the line with arrow
line_grob <- segmentsGrob(0.7, 0.8,
                          grobX(polyline_grob, 45),
                          grobY(polyline_grob, 45),
                          arrow = arrow(angle = 10, type = "closed"),
                          gp = gpar(fill = "black"))

# Create the text for annotation
txt_grob <- textGrob("line of best fit", 0.71, 0.81, just = c("left", "bottom"))

# Add arrow line and text annotation to the grob tree
gg_annotated <- grid::grobTree(
  gg,
  grid::grobTree(line_grob),
  grid::grobTree(txt_grob),
  vp = grid::viewport(x = unit(0.5, "npc"),
                      y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
                      width = unit(1, "npc"),
                      height = unit(1, "npc")
  )
)

# Render the plot
grid.draw(gg_annotated)


The result:

If I adjust the y1 value for segmentsGrob by trial and error, e.g. by changing the grobY line to: grobY(polyline_grob, 45) + unit(0.045, "npc"), it produces the plot as I want it to look:

However, this is an arbitrary shift of the y-coordinate.
Perhaps I have retrieved the wrong grob to use in the call to segmentsGrob. I have tried making the arrow end on other grobs in the grobTree but I have not been able to get this to work. How could I get the arrow to end on the line of best fit?

While I appreciate your effort, IMHO an easier approach to achieve your desired result would be to estimate the line of fit manually, then use two annotates to a add the segment and the label:
library(ggplot2)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ disp, mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = TRUE) +
  annotate(
    geom = "segment",
    xend = 250, yend = predict(mod, data.frame(disp = 250)),
    x = 300, y = 25,
    arrow = arrow(angle = 10, type = "closed")
  ) +
  annotate(
    geom = "label",
    x = 300,
    y = 25,
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0,
    label = "line of best fit",
    hjust = 0,
    vjust = 0
  )
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'


UPDATE The magic and flexibility of grid lies in the concept of the viewports. The issue is that you are drawing the segment and the text in the top viewport which is the plot itself. Instead, to get your desired result you have to draw into the viewport of the panel, which following the code in the referenced link from Paul Murrell's book could be achieved my moving down the tree of viewports like so:
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# Move down the viewport tree to the viewport of the panel
p
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'

grid.force()
panelvp <- grid.grep("panel",
  grobs = FALSE,
  viewports = TRUE, grep = TRUE
)
downViewport(panelvp)

gg_annotated <- grid::grobTree(
  line_grob,
  txt_grob,
  vp = grid::viewport(
    x = unit(0.5, "npc"),
    y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
    width = unit(1, "npc"),
    height = unit(1, "npc")
  )
)

grid.draw(gg_annotated)



Thank you for your solution which is helpful for me to see as another way of achieving my aim. I should have explained though that my main motivation is actually to learn more about how the grid package works so I have edited my original post to clarify this.

That's great thanks. This had me confused as the end of the arrow was pointing to the bottom of the confidence interval, which made me think maybe I had just selected the wrong grob.
